# Replication affects mysql service

Tags: mysql, replication

I've got a problem with my MySQL slave which receives updates from two masters.

Steps to reproduce:

1) I start the slave

2) The slave receives updates for 1-2 hours, after which fatal error crashes the server

> [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Aborting because of a corrupt database page in the system tablespace. Or, there was a failure in tagging the tablespace as corrupt.
>   2020-06-11 16:17:22 0x7fd250386700 InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140541265733376 in file ut0ut.cc line 910`

3) I add `innodb_force_recovery=4` to my config file and restart mysqld service to make it work again, set `innodb_force_recovery`to 0 in order to run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` - these actions allow me to restart mysql service and restore replication. However, the server fails again in a couple of hours.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: mysql version? Can you show the complete set of errors around your FATAL error message? This is probably a mysql bug. try searching https://bugs.mysql.com or if mariadb, https://jira.mariadb.org based on the assertion in ut0ut.cc

Comment: Hi @danblack, mysql version is 5.7.

Sorry, can't show the whole error. Today I've discovered that mysql.service can't start until I uncomment innodb_force_recovery. Do you know if there's anything I can do with this?

Comment: Is it the latest 5.7 version? If not upgrade there. Create another slave on 8.0 and see if this has the same problem. What errors are the mysql.service errors? (`systemctl show mysql.service; journalctl -u mysql.service`)

Comment: @danblack yes, the latest 5.7 version. creation of another slave is a bit problematic - the DB takes more than a terabyte.

systemctl show mysql.service output is too long, I won't be able to submit a comment)

anyway, what should be checked? i guess this can be handled by a couple of changes in the config file

Comment: A https://justpaste.it/ link maybe. journalctl from the last startup of the mysql service. Or just around the error. This really needs a bug report (to exist or lodge with sufficient information). Another slave is problematic because of its size but its the only way to try various things like mysql-8.0 or mariadb as a slave installs that don't have fallback paths. Is the datadir on LVM where you have snapshot and the ability to restore from snapshot?